# I am not getting sum of fields countOfDesine countOfImplement.. Please helpme

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

**JS**

```js
onchangeDesign(event) {
    var fieldName1=event.currentTarget.value;
    console.log('itemList11'+fieldName1);
    
    // this.itemList[event.currentTarget.dataset.key][fieldName1]=event.target.value;
    console.log('itemList33'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
    // this.isRiskMitigationRecordsChanged = true;
    this.itemList[event.target.dataset.index] = { ...this.itemList[event.target.dataset.index], DesignEffectiveVal__c: event.target.value };
    console.log('itemList55'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
    this.calculateRiskValues();

}

this.calculateRiskValues(){
    var countOfDesine = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<this.itemList.length;i++){ 
        console.log('itemListt23'+parseFloat(this.itemList[i].DesignEffectiveVal__c));
        this.countOfDesine=this.countOfDesine+parseFloat(this.itemList[i].DesignEffectiveVal__c);
    }
    var countOfImplement = 0;
    for(let i=0;i<this.itemList.length;i++){ 
        this.countOfImplement=this.countOfImplement+parseFloat(this.itemList[i].implementeffeVal__c);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="6" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="5"
        padding="around-small">
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name="Risk_Mitigation_Name__c"
            value={item.Risk_Mitigation_Name__c}
            data-name="Risk_Mitigation_Name__c"
            disabled="true"
            variant="label-hidden">
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="6" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="3"
        padding="around-small" class="slds-text-align_center">
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name="DesignEffectiveVal__c"
            class="design"
            variant="label-hidden"
            onchange={onchangeDesign}
            value={item.DesignEffectiveVal__c}
            data-id="DesignEffectiveVal__c"
            data-recordid={item.Id}
            data-index={index} 
            disabled={disableFieldsForGlobal}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" class="slds-text-align_center" padding="around-small"
        small-device-size="6" medium-device-size="4" large-device-size="3">
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name="implementeffeVal__c"
            class="implementation"
            variant="label-hidden"
            onchange={onchangeImple}
            value={item.implementeffeVal__c}
            data-id="implementeffeVal__c"
            data-recordid={item.Id}
            data-index={index}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

Comment: onchangeDesign(event) {
        var fieldName1=event.currentTarget.value;
        console.log('itemList11'+fieldName1);
        
        // this.itemList[event.currentTarget.dataset.key][fieldName1]=event.target.value;
        console.log('itemList33'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
        // this.isRiskMitigationRecordsChanged = true;
        this.itemList[event.target.dataset.index] = { ...this.itemList[event.target.dataset.index], DesignEffectiveVal__c: event.target.value };
        console.log('itemList55'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
        this.calculateRiskValues();

Answer (score 1):

When you define a method inside you class, you should not use `this.` as prefix. You must use is just to call an instance method.
So you should change `this.calculateRiskValues(){` to `calculateRiskValues() {`.

Moreover in that method you defined a local property using `var countOfDesine = 0;`, then you setted an instance property using `this.countOfDesine=`, they are not the same one. The same goes for `countOfImplement`.
If you need an instance property, a property that could be used in the template or in other methods, you should declare it outside the `calculateRiskValues` method.
I would also suggest to always prefer [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) over `var`.

Please note that you don't need two loops over the same array to calculate the sum, a single loop would be enough.
You should also take into account that if the value hold by those fields isn't a valid number (it may be null, undefined, '', etc...), you'll get [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (Not a Number) after parsing it and adding a number to `NaN` will always give `NaN`, so that's what you might get. To avoid it you could leverage [logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), i.e. `console.log(NaN || 0); // 0`.
To convert a value to a number you could use [unary plus (`+`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

```js
countOfDesine = 0; // instance property
countOfImplement = 0; // instance property

onchangeDesign(event) {
    const fieldName1 = event.currentTarget.value;
    console.log('itemList11'+fieldName1);
    
    // this.itemList[event.currentTarget.dataset.key][fieldName1]=event.target.value;
    console.log('itemList33'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
    // this.isRiskMitigationRecordsChanged = true;
    const itemIndex = +event.target.dataset.index;
    this.itemList[itemIndex] = { ...this.itemList[itemIndex], DesignEffectiveVal__c: event.target.value };
    console.log('itemList55'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
    this.calculateRiskValues();
}

calculateRiskValues() {
    for(const item of this.itemList) { 
        const designValue = +item.DesignEffectiveVal__c || 0;
        this.countOfDesine += designValue;

        const implValue = +item.implementeffeVal__c || 0;
        this.countOfImplement += implValue;
    }
}
```

By the way, if the instance properties `countOfDesine` and `countOfImplement` already hold the sum of those values, you don't need a loop to recalculate them when a value changes. Since you have the index of the item, you could just subtract the old value then add the new one.
I.E.

```js
onchangeDesign(event) {
    const itemIndex = +event.target.dataset.index;
    const item = this.itemList[itemIndex];
    const oldValue = +item.DesignEffectiveVal__c || 0;
    const newValue = +event.target.value || 0;
    this.countOfDesine += newValue - oldValue;
    this.itemList[itemIndex] = {
        ...item,
        DesignEffectiveVal__c: newValue
    };
    console.log('itemList55'+JSON.stringify(this.itemList));
}
```

Of course you should apply the same logic to `onchangeImple` method.